Change Pandas line spacing globally
How to change the line spacing of all tables displayed by Pandas in Colab or Jupyter Notebook? I.e. to do the same thing that this code does, but globally.
styles = [
    dict(selector="tr", props=[('line-height', '4px')])
]

df.style.set_table_styles(styles)


from pandas.io.formats.style import Styler
pd.DataFrame.style.apply = styles
Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html

Sadly it is not possible to add global settings like that one. You could make a function that applies the styles, that looks in my opinion a bit more readable. However, it is not big difference:
import pandas as pd

def format_df(df):
    return df.style.apply(lambda row: ['line-height: 4px' for _ in row])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [3, 4, 5]
})

# Apply the style
df = format_df(df)

